# Is there a way to determine if current step is a directory?

Tags: go, sftp

I need to implement sftp client that connects to a host, read all available files in a specified folder, then check if a particular file matches a pattern and copy it to according local directory. Problem is that i can't find a way to.

I tried to use client.Walk but cannot figure out a way to understand if this is a directory and skip it:

```
walker := client.Walk(startDir)
for walker.Step() {
    if err := walker.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        continue
    }


    filePath := walker.Path()
}
```

How can I determine if the current iteration is directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Walker.Stat()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/fs#Walker.Stat) to obtain info about the most recent file or directory visited by a call to [`Walker.Step()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/fs#Walker.Step). It returns you a value of type [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) which has an `IsDir()` method.

For example:

```
for walker.Step() {
    if err := walker.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        continue
    }

    if fi := walker.Stat(); fi.IsDir() {
        continue // Skip dir
    }

    // ...
}
```